# Can we have a [tour] magic link?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, magic-links

We used to have an About page, and accordingly, an [about] magic link. That's pretty handy! The About page is gone now - or at least it's no longer called About. It's now a Tour in the help menu and it's a very lovely tour (though its page title still seems to be 'About').

However, we don't have a [tour] magic link, which is *weird.* It tripped me up for weeks following the change - I kept trying to write [tour]. It would be even more weird if I were a new user who didn't know there was once a page called About. Nowadays I'm leaving comments to new users pointing them toward the [about] which is called a tour.

Could we have a [tour] magic link so we can call our [tour] a [tour]?

Comment: It's an Australian thing. It's not a tour, it's a walk[about].

Comment: Why am I nearly positive that we did this, and perhaps it's just broken? Checking on it.

Comment: Just a test: [tour]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[tour]` is now a reality.

For backwards compatibility, `[about]` still works, though it now also points to `/tour` and uses that name.

The page title has also been updated, as have all errant links to `/about` (please let us know if you find any laying around).

Comment: Hooray! \o/ You even updated the page title of the Tour page!