# Should [tour] take the place of [about] on the comment formatting page?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, help-center

The [comment formatting page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) is a bit out of date:

> `[about]`, `[meta-about]` – link to the About page. Link text is "about" (capitalization is respected). meta-about only works on meta sites.

While the old links [still work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228303/216955), I think it would make more sense to update this text to reflect the current structure since the "About" page no longer exists. `[tour]`, `[about]`, `[meta-tour]`, and `[meta-about]` all link to the same page; there is no "Meta Tour".

This would be the logical replacement to me:

> `[tour]` – link to the Tour page. Link text is "tour" (capitalization is respected).

If it's preferred to keep the `[about]` links around then at the very least I'd hope that `[tour]` could at least be mentioned on that page (currently it is not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been implemented and will appear with build 3747 on MSE/MSO and build 2870 on other sites.